# How to transform a Lindblad operator basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, unitarity, trace, open-quantum-systems

I'm trying to understand how to perform a unitary transformation on a set of traceless orthonormal Lindblad operators, following chapter 3.2.2 of *The Theory of Open Quantum Systems* by Breuer and Petruccione (also similar to this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindbladian)).

From equation 3.72 of the book, a set of traceless orthonormal Lindblad operators $\{A_i\}$ (with rates $\{\Gamma^A_i\}$) can be unitarily transformed into some other basis $\{B_i\}$ (with rates $\{\Gamma^B_i\}$) as

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\Gamma^B_i} B_i = \sum_j U_{i,j} \sqrt{\Gamma^A_j} A_j
\end{equation}

where "$U_{i,j}$ is a unitary matrix". I'm assuming that the book means that $U$ is a unitary operator and $U_{i,j}$ is a scalar matrix element (otherwise I'm even more confused).

I have a number of questions about $U$:

1. Are there any properties that $U$ needs to have other than being unitary?
2. If I have a particular traceless orthonormal operator basis $\{B_i\}$ in mind that I want to transform into, how do I determine the $U$ to do this (if even possible)? I know that $B_i=\sum_j \text{Tr}[B_i A^{\dagger}_j]A_j$ but it's unclear to me how the $\sqrt{\Gamma^A_j}$ plays a role.
3. How does this Lindblad operator transformation work when only a single rate $\Gamma^A_j$ is non-zero? Let's say that $\Gamma^A_{j'}$ is a positive real number and $\Gamma^A_{j\neq j'}=0$. Then $\sqrt{\Gamma^B_i} B_i=U_{i,j'}\sqrt{\Gamma^A_{j'}} A_{j'}$. Not only does this make every operator $B_i$ proportional to $A_{j'}$ and thus $\{B_i\}$ doesn't form any kind of complete operator basis regardless of $U$, but also $U_{i,j'}$ might not even be a non-negative real number which would violate the idea of every $\Gamma$ being a non-negative real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answers to questions 1-3 are as follows:

1. The operators $U$ which preserve diagonal form of the Liuvillian should obey the property
   \begin{equation}
     \sum_{k} U_{ik} \Gamma_k^A U_{j,k}^* = \Gamma_i^B\delta_{ij},
   \end{equation}
   i. e. they should transform a diagonal matrix $\Gamma_{i}^A\delta_{ij}$ to a diagonal matrix $\Gamma_{i}^B\delta_{ij}$. The decay rates $\Gamma_{i}^B$
   are the permutations of $\Gamma_i^A$, and $U$ may be composed of permutations of subspaces with different $\Gamma_i^A$ and arbitrary unitaries within
   the subspaces belonging to a single $\Gamma_i^A$.
2. For arbitrary traceless orthonormal basis, the Liuvillian may not be in *diagonal* form.
   The coefficients $a_{ij}$ of the *first standard form* (see Breuer and Petruccione) can be found with a unitary transformation;
3. I show below that the transformation $\sqrt{\Gamma_i^A}A_i = U_{ij}\sqrt{\Gamma_j^B}B_j$ is equivalent to $A_i = U_{ij}B_j$.
   Therefore, there is nothing special when some of the $\Gamma_i$ are zeros, and all $B_j$ remain orthonormal.

The argumentation is as follows.

Breuer and Petruccione define the *the first standard form* of the Liuvillian as
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{D}(\rho) = \sum_{ij} a_{ij} \left(F_i\rho F_j^\dagger - \frac{1}{2}\{\rho, F_j^\dagger F_i\}\right).
\end{equation}
It is not unique, as it is invariant under the following transformations of the operators $F_i$ and the matrix $a_{ij}$:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
  F_i = u_{ki} F'_k,\\
  a_{kl}' = u_{ki} a_{ij}u^*_{lj} ,
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
where $u_{ki}$ is an arbitrary unitary matrix.

The question is about the non--uniqueness of the *diagonal* form of the Liuvillian. The latter is obtained from the *first standard form* by
choosing the unitary $u$ which diagonalizes the matrix $a_{ij}$:
\begin{equation}
  u_{ki} u^*_{lj} a_{ij} = \Gamma_k^A\delta_{kl}, 
\end{equation}
%which also transforms the set of operators $F_i$ into $A_i$:
\begin{equation}
  F_i = u_{ki} A_k.
\end{equation}
The choice of the operators $A_k$ is also not unique: there always exist unitary matrices $U_{ij}$ which preserve the diagonal form of the
Liuvillian after the transformation
%and sets of $B_i$
\begin{equation}
  A_i = U_{ij}B_j.
\end{equation}
%which preserves the diagonal form of the Liuvillian and therefore the matrix $a_{ij} = \Gamma_i^A\delta_{ij}$:
%Using the transformation law for the matrix $a_{ij}$, one gets the condition
The condition for preserving the diagonal form follows from the transformation law for the matrix $a_{ij}$:
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{k,l} U_{ik} \Gamma_k^A U_{j,k}^* = \Gamma_i^B\delta_{ij}.
\end{equation}
The class of unitaries $U$ which turns the diagonal matrix $\Gamma_{k}^A\delta_{kl}$ into a diagonal matrix is quite restricted. Such unitaries include:

1. independent unitary rotations of the subspaces belonging to the same value of $\Gamma_k$ (nontrivial when there exist $\Gamma_k = \Gamma_l$, $k\ne l$),
2. permutations of such subspaces.

Therefore, the sets of $\Gamma_k^A$ and $\Gamma_k^B$ differ only by permutation, whereas the operators $B_i$ from the question may be nontrivial linear
combinations of $A_i$ providing that some of $\Gamma_k^A$ coincide.

Also, $U_{ij}$ is nonzero only providing $\Gamma_i^A = \Gamma_j^B$. Therefore,
the transformation $A_i = U_{ij}B_j$ is equivalent to  $\sqrt{\Gamma_i^A}A_i = U_{ij}\sqrt{\Gamma_j^B}B_j$ which was in the question.